# Vector spanning a space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does a matrix such as:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f
\end{pmatrix}
$

Which is a $3\times 2$ matrix span the third dimension if possible. I know its homegenious equation as infinite solutions but.... thats not being intuitive. I wanted to know this to clarify my view on onto transformations.

Comment: Do you want to know whether the column space of the $3\times 2$ matrix is $\mathbb{R}^3$? Well, no, because the rank of the matrix is at most $2$.

Comment: But its homogeneous equation has many solutions...

Comment: @egreg, what about a 2X3 matrix of the same form? If not... does that mean  for onto transformation the matrix always have to be square?

Comment: What do you mean by "But its homogeneous equation has many solutions.."?

Comment: @ArsenBerk, Ax=0 has many solns.

Comment: @bzal If the rank of $A$ is $2$, then the system $Ax=0$ only has one solution.

Comment: If you want to go through that way, I suggest you to find a matrix $A$ which is independent from some other variables like $a, b, c, d, e, f$. Otherwise, with variables $a, b, c, d, e, f$ and vector $x$, you may have infinite solutions dependent of what $A$ is as you said.

Comment: @egreg..... theres a free variable x3, ?

Comment: @Arsenberk.... wanted to generalize it for pissible values of matrix

Comment: Then I suggest you to try it with a rank $1$ matrix and a rank $2$ matrix because it cannot have rank $3$ or more. For example a rank $2$ matrix can be in the form of $\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & b\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, which gives trivial solution.

Comment: @Arsenberg....... come to  think a rank 1 also has infinite solns for Ax=0. But, what about a 2X3 matrix of the same form, it also doesnt span third dimension? Does that mean  for onto transformation the matrix always have to be square and that   a transformation from third to second dim, Cannot be onto? (Sorry... im on cell phone...  so using abbrv.)

Comment: @bzal Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in general to span $\mathbb{R^n}$ we need at least n (independent) vectors therefore the columns of the given matrix span

- a plane if they are linearly independent, that is rank(A)=2
- line if they are not linearly independent, that is rank(A)=1